# How do I separate api / async request logic from react components when using recoil

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, recoiljs

So at the moment I am having to put my request / api logic directly into my components because what I need to do a lot of the time is set state based on the response I get from the back end.

Below is a function that I have on my settings page that I use to save the settings to recoil after the user hits save on the form:

```
const setUserConfig = useSetRecoilState(userAtoms.userConfig);

const submitSettings = async (values: UserConfigInterface) => {
    try {
        const { data: {data} } = await updateUser(values);

        setUserConfig({
            ...data
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('settings form error: ', error);
    }
}
```

This works perfectly...I just dont want the function in my component as most of my components are getting way bigger than they need to be.

I have tried making a separate file to do this but I can only use the recoil hooks (in this instance `useSetRecoilState`) inside of components and it just complains when I try and do this outside of a react component.

I have tried implementing this with recoils `selector` and `selectorFamily` functions but it gets kind of complicated. Here is how I have tried it inside of a file that has atoms / selectors only:

```
export const languageProgress = atom<LanguageProgress>({
    key: "LanguageProgress",
    default: {
        level: 1,
        xp: 0,
        max_xp: 0
    }
})

export const languageProgressUpdate = selectorFamily<LanguageProgress>({
    key: "LanguageProgress",
    get: () => async () => {
        try {
            const { data: { data } } = await getLanguageProgress();

            return data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('get language progress error');
        }
    },
    set: (params:object) => async ({set}) => {
        try {
            const { data: { data } } = await updateLanguageProgress(params);

            set(languageProgress, {
                level: data.level,
                xp: data.xp,
                max_xp: data.max_xp
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('language progress update error: ', error);
        }
    }
});
```

What I want to do here is get the values I need from the back end and display it in the front which I can do in the selector function get but now I have 2 points of truth for this...my languageProgress atom will initially be incorrect as its not getting anything from the database so I have to use `useGetRevoilValue` on the `languageProgressUpdate` selector I have made but then when I want to update I am updating the atom and not the actual value.

I cannot find a good example anywhere that does what I am trying to here (very suprisingly as I would have thought it is quite a common way to do things...get data from back end and set it in state.) and I can't figure out a way to do it without doing it in the component (as in the first example). Ideally I would like something like the first example but outside of a component because that solution is super simple and works for me.

Answer (score 0):

So I dont know if this is the best answer but it does work and ultimately what I wanted to do was seperate the logic from the screen component.

The answer in my situation is a bit long winded but this is what I used to solve the problem: https://medium.com/geekculture/crud-with-recoiljs-and-remote-api-e36581b77168

Essentially the answer is to put all the logic into a hook and get state from the api and set it there.

Answer (score 0):

> get data from back end and set it in state

You may be looking for [`useRecoilValueLoadable`](https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/core/useRecoilValueLoadable/):

> "This hook is intended to be used for reading the value of asynchronous selectors. This hook will subscribe the component to the given state."

Here's a quick demonstration of how I've previously used it. To quickly summarise: you pass `useRecoilValueLoadable` a selector (that you've defined somewhere outside the logic of the component), that selector grabs the data from your API, and that all gets fed back via `useRecoilValueLoadable` as an array of 1) the current state of the value returned, and 2) the content of that API call.

Note: in this example I'm passing an array of values to the selector each of which makes a separate API call.

##### App.js

```
const { state, contents } = useRecoilValueLoadable(myQuery(arr));

if (state.hasValue && contents.length) {
  // `map` over the contents
}
```

##### selector.js

```
import { selectorFamily } from 'recoil';

export const myQuery = selectorFamily({
  key: 'myQuery',
  get: arr => async () => {

    const promises = arr.map(async item => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`/endpoint/${item.id}`);
        if (response.ok) return response.json();
        throw Error('API request not fulfilled');
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });

    const items = await Promise.all(promises);
    return items;

  }
});
```